# How i dont display empty and null rows in yii

Tags: yii

How I do not display empty and null rows in yiiframework with listview.
Many rows in database are null.When I want to show data in view.php I see many null rows.I see a data on the other page.
can I see just rows with data.

Comment: You should give an example of what you have already tried, and what your code looks like. This looks like a pretty straightforward WHERE or if/then/else solution.

Answer (score 0):

The CListView widget uses a template to render each row of data.
In the skeleton generated by Gii, the index.php file has a CListView widget that uses the _view.php file to display row data.
You only have to check if a field is null and don't show it.

If you are aking for the autogenerated view.php file, the default is CDetailView
At this place, you can use the "visible" element of the attribute item:

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'field1',
            'visible'=>$model->field1!=null,
        ),
        ..............
```

See [attributes property of CDetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail) and [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)

Comment: Yes, he's asking for ListView, but he says: "I want to show data in view.php I see many null rows" and I assumed he uses as template the autogenerated view.php file, that uses the CDetailView widget. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your model, put a condition to filter null/empty values before rendering the result to your view.

```
    public function search() {

    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('table_column', $this->tableColumn, false );
    $criteria->condition .= "another_table_column IS NOT NULL"; //this will filter null values
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [afterFind()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) method in your Model to change the value displayed in the view so that a null value is shown as "NA" or some other value like that.